# Dynamic sed to replace part of string

Tags: sed

Well I have a project that was made upgrade from php 7.4 to 8.1

so many functions in someway doesn't work as before because in php 8.1 doesn't accept null anymore.

So I want to replace all functions with a script so I could automation it.

Example:

```
         line not affected before
explode(self::RULE_KEY_SEPARATOR, $key); somethingAfter
         testeBefore  explode(somthing, $key); somethingAfter
line not affected after
```

Output:

```
         line not affected before
explode(self::RULE_KEY_SEPARATOR, $key ?? ''); somethingAfter
         testeBefore  explode(something, $key ?? ''); somethingAfter
line not affected after
```

So a solution could be add `?? ''` before close the parentesis of the function

here a snippet of what I tried to do: https://sed.js.org/?snippet=xqo9gd

I don't know if this is possible with sed.

If someone could help. I would appreciate :)

**EDIT:**

if snippet isn't available I will let here my try and output

I tried:

```
's/^\(.*\?\?\).*explode\(.*\).*/explode(self::RULE_KEY_SEPARATOR, $key ?? '\'''\''\);/g'
```

Output:

```
         line not affected before
explode(self::RULE_KEY_SEPARATOR, $key ?? '');
explode(self::RULE_KEY_SEPARATOR, $key ?? '');
line not affected after
```

As expected since is not dynamically...

Comment: Please add your code here as well. The snippet won't live as long as this question

Comment: @Sam alright, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current command has a few issues;

- You create a capture group but do not utilize it therefore losing all leading whitespace
- After `explode`, you are creating another capture group rather than matching the parenthesis literally
- After the second capture group, you use a greedy regex to capture and discard the remainder of the line.
- You are hardcoding the replace value rather than using the values already present

You can try this `sed`

```
$ sed "s/explode([^)]*/& ?? ''/" input_file
         line not affected before
explode(self::RULE_KEY_SEPARATOR, $key ?? ''); somethingAfter
         testeBefore  explode(somthing, $key ?? ''); somethingAfter
line not affected after
```

Comment: Whaat?! impressive, I think just would have a bug there that i tried to avoid 
imagine this example:
         testeBefore  explode(somthing, $key ?? ''); somethingAfter,
shouldn't affect this line

Comment: Finally I got it "/\?\?\ ''/! s/explode([^)]*/& ?? ''/g"

Comment: "/\?\?\ ''/! s/explode([^)]*/& ?? ''/g" well, this is closed but still a problem with          testeBefore  explode(somthing, $key->hello() ); somethingAfter the output is testeBefore  explode(somthing, $key->hello(?? '') ); somethingAfter, how to make it testeBefore  explode(somthing, $key->hello() ?? ''); somethingAfter instead?

Comment: @IndexError Does this help? `sed -E "s/(explode\([^)]*(\)[^)]*)*)(\);)/\1 ?? ''\3/g"`

Comment: yeah would work, but failed on "testeBefore something( explode(somthing, $key->hello()) ); somethingAfter"
 check this out: https://sed.js.org/?snippet=7qodEK, this got way more complex than I thought would get

Comment: @IndexError `-E "/\?\?\ ('')?/! s/(explode\([^)]*(\)[^)]*)*)(\);)/\1 ?? ''\3/g"`